# SQL Group By Sub Query

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, max

I dont fully understand sub queries fully on how they can be accessed by the outer query, so i need some help with this question. Here are the four schema's.

```
Movie(title, year, director, budget, earnings)
Actor(stagename, realname, birthyear)
ActedIn(stagename, title, year, pay)
CanWorkWith(stagename, director)
```

Find the name(s) of the actors(s) with the highest pay for acting in a movie.
From what i got, it is asking to find the highest paid actor for each movie...But on second thought the brackets may indicate that it could who has been paid the highest and maybe a couple have the same amount. ANyways..

What i have

```
SELECT A.realname
FROM ActedIn A
WHERE A.stagename IN ( SELECT A1.title, A1.year, MAX(pay)
                       FROM ActedIn A1
                       GROUP BY title, year )
```

I know WHERE A.stagename IN is completely wrong, i just have no idea how to link it back.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough if i well understood :

```
SELECT A.realname
FROM ActedIn A
WHERE pay = (SELECT MAX(pay) FROM ActedIn B WHERE B.stagename = A.stageman)
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of subqueries are simple. It is just a matter of perspective. When you write a subquery it is first segment which is processed. Since it is completely processed before the outer query, the output of a sub query should make sense to the outer query. In the example you provided above,

```
SELECT A.realname FROM ActedIn A WHERE A.stagename IN 
( SELECT A1.stagename FROM CanWorkWith A1 )
```

When this query runs, stagename from CanWorkWIth is processed first and gives out stagename as output. The outer query, which is expecting A.stagename recieves this values and then the outer query is executed.

There is no limit in how you write the subqueries.

I hope you see the point. Now that you understand how sub query works, i encourage you to solve the problem yourself and ask here with your new sql. Good luck.

Comment: Would this work? SELECT A.realname FROM ActedIn A WHERE A.stagename IN 
    ( SELECT A1.stagename, MAX(pay) FROM ActedIn A1 GROUP BY A1.stagename )

Comment: No that wont. In your updated query, the A.stagename is expecting just the stagename but your subquery is giving the stagename and their maximum pay. So this query will not work. Look at aleroot's solution. That should help you. Try few other queries to get a good grasp on how sub queries work. Good luck.